# Neo4j User node gets deleted after running separate User tests Node.js

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I'm facing a bit of a weird issue, I'm writing tests for the server and for the issue at hand I have two types of nodes `User` which has a `uid` parameter, and `Alert` which has a `userId` parameter set on `User.uid`. So I set up tests for C.R.U.D. operations for both and for each test I set up a `User` with different `uid`s respectively `UserTestUser` and `AlertTestUser`. Now, for the `Alert` nodes instead of deleting them I set up a relationship `(User)-[:DELETED]->(Alert)` ( I'm experimenting with the knowledge graph ). For the `User` node instead I do delete the actual node. The weird part is that when the `User` tests run it deletes the user created in the Alert tests. I checked, double checked and triple checked.. the `uid`s passed to the cyphers are the correct ones.

## Alert delete

```
exports.deleteAlertById = async (id, req, uid) => {
  // console.log('neoAlert.deleteAlertById alert id :', id);
  console.log('neoAlert.deleteAlertById uid :', uid);
  const driver = neo4j.getDriver();
  const session = driver.session();
  const request = JSON.stringify(req);
  //console.log(request);
  const res = await session.executeWrite((tx) =>
    tx.run(
      `
      with apoc.convert.fromJsonMap($request) as request
      MATCH (a:Alert {id: $id})
      match (u:User {uid: $uid})
      merge (u)-[r:DELETED]->(a)
      create (u)-[rq:MADE_QUERY]->(q:Query)-[rf:FROM_IP]->(ip:Ip)-[rqf:FOR]->(a)
      set q = request, 
      ip.ip = request.ip
      RETURN a as alert, u as user
      `,
      {
        id: id,
        request: request,
        uid: uid,
      }
    )
  );
  await session.close();
  console.log(`Neo4j deleted alert`);
  const records = res.records;
  const user = records[0].get('user');
  console.log('Neo4j deleteAlert user is: ', user);

  return;
};
```

and the prints are:

```
neoAlert.deleteAlertById uid : AlertTestUser
Neo4j deleted alert
Neo4j deleteAlert user is:  Node {
  identity: Integer { low: 8, high: 0 },
  labels: [ 'User' ],
  properties: { uid: 'AlertTestUser' },
  elementId: '8'
}
```

## User delete

```
exports.deleteUserById = async (uid) => {
  console.log('Neo4j deleteUserById user uid : ', uid);
  const driver = neo4j.getDriver();
  const session = driver.session();
  const res = await session.executeWrite((tx) =>
    tx.run(
      `
    match (u:User {uid: $uid})
    with u, properties(u) as user
    detach delete u
    return user
    `,
      { uid: uid }
    )
  );
  await session.close();
  const records = res.records;

  records.forEach((record) => {
    const deleted = record.get('user');
    console.log('Neo4j deleted user: ', deleted);
  }) 
  console.log('Neo4j deleted users', records.length);
  return;
}
```

and the prints are:

```
Neo4j deleteUserById user uid :  UserTestUser
Neo4j deleted user:  {
  lastLogin: Integer { low: 564295870, high: 26 },
  zipCode: '40129',
  country: 'Italy',
  address: 'someUpdatedAddress',
  city: 'Bologna',
  phoneVerified: true,
  totalRating: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 },
  signUpDate: Integer { low: 11223344, high: 0 },
  photoUrl: 'https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors',
  emailVerified: false,
  createdAt: '2022-10-24T18:33:10.801Z',
  uid: 'UserTestUser',
  stripeId: 'cus_MfrARfDEzJNSmp',
  ratings: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 },
  averageRating: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 },
  __v: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 },
  name: 'vincenzo calia',
  _id: '6356da66f5ed48ae29f0bb6c',
  id: '6356da66f5ed48ae29f0bb6c',
  region: 'Emilia-Romagna',
  fcmToken: 'someNewToken',
  email: 'someTestEmail7@gmail.com',
  updatedAt: '2022-10-24T18:44:16.817Z'
}
Neo4j deleted users 1
```

Both methods show the correct `uid` to match a `User` and the correct user only is deleted in the User tests, so it looks it's all ok..

The difference I see it in the graph..

## Graph after alert tests only

[image]

## Graph after both tests

[image]

as you can see the `User` node with uid AlertTestUser is gone..

How can that be?? As the graph after the User tests is left untouched, I would expect to see the the same graph as in the Alert tests only also after the User tests..

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong here??

As always many thanks for your help
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug.. In the saveUser I was using `merge`

```
with apoc.convert.fromJsonMap($json) as json
    merge (u:User) set u = json
    return u as user
```

instead of `create`

```
with apoc.convert.fromJsonMap($json) as json
    create (u:User) set u = json
    return u as user
```

and of course it was finding the User node created in the Alert tests, and deleting it in the `deleteUser` method..

To use merge for new node creation is mandatory to specify a unique property, uid in my case as

```
with apoc.convert.fromJsonMap($json) as json
    merge (u:User {uid: json.uid}) set u = json
    return u as user
```

, so it won't match any existing node but will create it and then set the rest of the parameters, instead of creating a new empty node and set the rest of parameters as when using create.